# Get XSI Type from XML in Perl

Tags: perl

There're bunch of XML files in different sub-folders in a root folder. Some of them has following contents.

XML-1

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Channels>
    <Genre xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="News">
        <CableType>XY-1</CableType>
        <Name>C-SPAN</Name>
    </Genre>
    <displayName>C-SPAN Network</displayName>
    <Genre xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Sports">
        <CableType>XY-2</CableType>
        <Name>Fox</Name>
    </Genre>
    <displayName>Fox Sports</displayName>
</Channels>
```

XML-2

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Channels>
    <Genre xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="News">
        <CableType>XY-1</CableType>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
    </Genre>
    <displayName>ABC News</displayName>
    <Genre xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Movies">
        <CableType>XY-2</CableType>
        <Name>HBO</Name>
    </Genre>
    <displayName>HBO Movies</displayName>
    <Genre xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="News">
        <CableType>XY-3</CableType>
        <Name>CBS</Name>
    </Genre>
    <displayName>CBS News</displayName>
</Channels>
```

XML-3

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Channels>
    <Genre xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="News">
        <CableType>XY-1</CableType>
        <Name>PBS</Name>
    </Genre>
    <displayName>PBS News</displayName>
    <Genre xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Sports">
        <CableType>XY-@</CableType>
        <Name>ESPN</Name>
    </Genre>
    <displayName>ESPN Network</displayName>
</Channels>
```

Goal is to go through all sub-folders and parse the XML and look for ***xsi:type*** value. Most XMLs are only expected to have one  ***xsi:type=News*** in it. But in this case, XML-2 has 2 ***xsi:type=News*** in it.

Below is a perl script that i could come up with so far to go through all sub-folders and find XML files and add it to a array list. Now need some help on finding XML files having more than one ***xsi:type=News***.

```
my $dir = "C:\\perl_scripts";
use File::Find;

find(
{
    wanted => \&findfiles,
},
    $dir
);

sub findfiles
{   
}

my @file_list;
find ( sub {
    return unless -f;       #Must be a file
    return unless /\.xml$/;  #Must end with `.xml` suffix
    push @file_list, $File::Find::name;
}, $dir );

foreach my $title (@file_list) {
    say $title;
}
```

How is it possible to get the total number of ***xsi:type=News*** > 1 and then print it on console?

For above 3 XMLs, it should print **XML-2**.

**UPDATE:**

Here's the final code,

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $dir = "C:\\perl_scripts";
use File::Find;

find(
{
    wanted => \&findfiles,
},
    $dir
);

sub findfiles
{   
}

my @file_list;
find ( sub {
    return unless -f;       #Must be a file
    return unless /\.xml$/;  #Must end with `.xml` suffix
    push @file_list, $File::Find::name;
}, $dir );

foreach my $title (@file_list){
    my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $title);
    my %xsi_type;
    for my $node ($doc->findnodes('//Genre')) {
         $xsi_type{ $node->getAttribute('xsi:type') }++;
    }
    if ($xsi_type{News} > 1) {
        print 'Found file with more than one xsi:type="News" ==> ';
        say $title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) to determine if a file has more than one tag with `xsi:type="News"` :

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Channels>
    <Genre xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="News">
        <CableType>XY-1</CableType>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
    </Genre>
    <displayName>ABC News</displayName>
    <Genre xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Movies">
        <CableType>XY-2</CableType>
        <Name>HBO</Name>
    </Genre>
    <displayName>HBO Movies</displayName>
    <Genre xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="News">
        <CableType>XY-3</CableType>
        <Name>CBS</Name>
    </Genre>
    <displayName>CBS News</displayName>
</Channels>';

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $xml);
my %xsi_type;
for my $node ($doc->findnodes('//Genre')) {
     $xsi_type{ $node->getAttribute('xsi:type') }++;
}
if ($xsi_type{News} > 1) {
    say 'Found file with more than one xsi:type="News"';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for the second `Genre` with the `News` type.<sup>[1]</sup>

Also, File::Find::Rule is much cleaner than File::Find.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find::Rule          qw( );
use XML::LibXML               qw( );
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext qw( );

my $root_dir_qfn = $ARGV[0] // ".";

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new;
$xpc->registerNs( xsi => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" );

for my $qfn (
   File::Find::Rule
   ->file
   ->name( "*.xml" )
   ->in( $dir_qfn )
) {
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => $xml );

   if ( () = $xpc->findnodes( '/Channels/Genre[@xsi:type="News"][2]', $doc ) ) {
      warn( "$qfn: Found multiple News channels\n" );
   }
}
```

---

1. The previous answer suggests looping through all the `Genres` elements, but there's no need to do that.

   This answer also shows how to use namespaces correctly. Relying on a specific prefix is not acceptable since any prefix can be used as long as it has the correct namespace associated with it. For example, `<Genre xmlns:foo="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" foo:type="News">` is just as legitimate, and my program will correctly identify this element (unlike the previous answer).